# Matplotlib and Django: how to prevent the shifting of the figure while the page loading?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, charts

I use Matplotlib to  display charts in a web browser. Consider this minimal example:

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from tests import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^test/$', views.page_test),
    url(r'^test/barchart_test.png$', views.barchart_test),
    url(r'^test/piechart_test.png$', views.piechart_test),
)
```

**views.py**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def page_test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')

def barchart_test(request):
    x = range(0, 2)
    y = (40, 80)
    width = 0.20

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    fig.frameon = False

    ax1.bar(x, y, width, align='center', color=('#44A744', '#D95F61'))

    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    plt.close(fig)
    return response

def piechart_test(request):
    num = [2, 6, 10]
    lab = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

    ax1.pie(
        num,
        labels=lab,
        )

    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    plt.close(fig)
    return response
```

**template (test.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="barchart_test">
        <h2 align="center">Bar</h2>
        <img align="center" title="Bar title" src="barchart_test.png">
    </div>

    <div id="piechart_test">
        <h2 align="center">Pie</h2>
        <img align="center" title="Pie title" src="piechart_test.png">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my web browser (Chrome Version 38.0.2125.122) the figures have not their final location when they are first displayed. At the end of the loading, they move to the right position.

Is it possible to prevent this shifting and see the figures immediately at the right place ?